# "ERROR 504 - GATEWAY TIMEOUT" in Joomla! 'Administrator' Only

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, fatal-error, hosting

I have a Joomla! 3.8 site that is running fine on the front-end. However, when I try to access `/administrator/` I get the following error:

**ERROR 504 - GATEWAY TIMEOUT**

There is nothing new in `/administrator/error_log`. However, in the `error_log` of the root directory, there is this log hundreds of times:

```
[20-Jun-2018 11:00:40 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home7/userfolder/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home7/userfolder/public_html/templates/consultpress/error.php on line 42
[20-Jun-2018 11:00:40 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home7/userfolder/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php70/lib/php') in /home7/userfolder/public_html/templates/consultpress/error.php on line 42
```

Line 42:

```
require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php');
```

Is this related to the **ERROR 504**? If not, what could be the issue?

I've contacted the host (BlueHost) and they assure me it is a Joomla! issue. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up moving the site to another host and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This issue also exists in Gantry4 templates.  Below is the fix for that:

```
if (!class_exists('JDocumentRendererHead')) {
   require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php');
}
```

Comment: Well, that solved the error in the error log, but had nothing to do with the 504 error. :/

Comment: Who is your host?  Have you reached out to them?  504's can be caused from their side as well.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the question. Bluehost says it is a Joomla! issue.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  Check out this advice from Akeeba guys: https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/admin-tools/Ticket/17004-service-unavailable-technical-description-504-gateway-time-out-the-web-server-is-not-responding.html

Comment: I've disabled error reporting via `configuration.php`, disabled Admin Tools via database, uploaded default `.htaccess`, and upgraded to PHP 7.0...nothing has changed. :(